# Compound shape in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I need to create the following shape in CSS:  [shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Wcb.png)
I've found different shapes online, but they are arrows, hexagons and so on; nothing really helpful for my shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, feel free to tweak values as needed. Using a `::before` pseudo element lets you create that added outcropping section without needing a second separate HTML element.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```